# Enabling mod_expire depending on request

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-caching, mod-expires

Instead of generating links to `file.js`, I'm calculating a version number or hash sum and linking to `file--bbe02f946d.js`. I'm using the following redirect rule to then serve the current version of the file:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)--[a-z0-9]+\.js$ $1.js
```

Now, I want to set extremely far away [Expires](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_expires.html) headers for those requests:

```
ExpiresActive on
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"
```

This works fine, but applies to not yet versioned resources (`/file.js` requests) too. How can  I set the expires headers only for the requests matching the RewriteRule? Normally, I'd use [`<LocationMatch>`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#locationmatch), but that's not available since the application must be able to run on arbitrary servers where I can just modify htaccess.

Comment: I suggest 1) setting some environment variable in rewrite rule using `[E]` flag ( http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_e ) .. 2) and then use [Header](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html#header) to set appropriate header based on such variable value/presence

Comment: If the above will not work and you will not find any other working solution .. then maybe you can serve these versioned and not-yet-versioned resources from different folders somehow -- then you could easily apply such headers in local .htaccess file.

Comment: @LazyOne Thanks, I'll try do use variables. Too sad you're too lazy to  write a full answer ;)

Comment: I'm not really an Apache guy .. and have not done this myself in the past -- I'm "specializing" on URL rewrite rules. I could try and implement this myself .. but I do not have access to my dev Apache box outside of work and almost all production servers are IIS-powered (yeah -- too lazy to install Apache on some virtual environment at home).

Answer (score 0):

You could add a new mime type with htaccess and set custom expire headers.

Example using .xjs

```
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
    AddType application/x-javascript .xjs
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gzip.c>
mod_gzip_item_include file \.xjs$
</IfModule>

<FilesMatch ".(xjs)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=43200"
</FilesMatch>
```

or just use regex in `FilesMatch` to match your js file

```
<FilesMatch "--[a-z0-9]+\.js$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=43200"
</FilesMatch>
```